# RestSharp Screen Scraping

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, rest, screen-scraping, restsharp

Problem: We have a workflow that is supremely slow and I'm trying to rewrite it in restful / MVC3 using RestSharp (which ive never used before).  Soo far I'm able to do the initial GET of the webiste, but when I do my first follow up POST (which simulates clicking on a checkbox, and clicking on the continue button to go to the next page), I keep getting the following error: `405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed.`
The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) was used to attempt access.

Im probably doing something wrong in the code.  I know the website that im trying to "screen scrape" allows these types of requests as we have an ancient slow workflow foundation thats currently working but its supremely slow and out dated. Side note the website is in asp.net and requires the session state.

here's my code:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://thewebsite.com/");            
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");            
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

var response = client.Execute(request);

string responseString = string.Empty;
if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{                                 
    string ViewState = string.Empty;
    string EventValidation = string.Empty;
    request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);    

    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");                
    request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;                
    responseString = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(response.Content);

    request.AddParameter("__EVENTTARGET", "");
    request.AddParameter("__EVENTARGUMENT", "");
    request.AddParameter("ctl00%24MainContent%24cbAgree", "on");
    request.AddParameter("ctl00%24MainContent%24ctl01", "Continue");                

    //parses & adds the session variables from the raw html to keep the sessionstate
    Match m = RegexMatch(responseString, @"<input(\s\w+?[^=]*?=""[^""]*?"")*?\s+?id=""(\S+?\s)*?__VIEWSTATE(\s\S+?)*?"".*?value=""(?<value>.*?)"" />");
    if (m.Success)
        ViewState = m.Groups["value"].Value;

    m = RegexMatch(responseString, @"<input(\s\w+?[^=]*?=""[^""]*?"")*?\s+?id=""(\S+?\s)*?__EVENTVALIDATION(\s\S+?)*?"".*?value=""(?<value>.*?)"" />");
    if (m.Success)
        EventValidation = m.Groups["value"].Value;

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ViewState) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(EventValidation))
    {
        request.AddParameter("__VIEWSTATE", UrlEncode(ViewState));
        request.AddParameter("__EVENTVALIDATION", UrlEncode(EventValidation));
    }

    response = client.Execute(request);
}
else
{
    //error in the GET
    responseString = response.StatusDescription + " --------------------" + HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(response.Content);
}
```

Comment: The RestSharp request.AddParameter has an overload the specifies on where to add the parameter. Can you specify that to be the RequestBody  as request.AddParameter("__EVENTTARGET","",ParameterType.RequestBody)

Comment: Rajesh,  Thank you for the response, sadly i had already previously tried that (i just did again for a sanity check), and it still gives me that 405 error :(

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the request with Fiddler to make sure on how your raw request looks like when performing the call?

Comment: i have and the parameters, with the session matches... (i use chrone extension RestClient)

Comment: The easiest way to trace down the problem would be that you navigate on the website with Fiddler on from the page where you perform the POST operation and see how the request looks like and then compare it with the request you get when doing it programatically.

Comment: Rajesh, thanks for your help, however i managed to get it working with HTMLAgilityPack. The post parameters all matched fine after looking through the post data. Anyway HTMLAgility Pack worked in like 6 lines (i had to download the source of htmlagilitypack and do a minor change by dbanck.de/2010/01/09/post-data-with-net-html-agility-pack , but man it works like a charm!